# Python 2.5.4 throws 'NoneType is not callable' whereas 2.5.1 works fine

Tags: python

I understand the question might well be too vague, but just in case anyone seen this or can have any clues. I have an application which works just fine under python 2.5.1. But when running it on Python 2.5.4, it starts giving "NoneType is not callable".

I have checked changelogs between the versions, but there are quite a few changes, and it's really hard to say what might be related.

Can you give any hint please where to start digging further?

EDIT: Clearly something is None, but the question is why it is not None under 2.5.1. I was hoping that there is a good known issue for this, so that this question might hit it.

EDIT 2: It has just become clear that the error occurs when trying to import win32com.client. Any clues how to work around it?

Comment: The error message should tell you exactly where to start looking. Something is returning `None`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm posting this answer on behalf of an "Anonymous user" (presumably the OP who had not logged in properly?!) who had written this as an edit to the question (edit got rejected because it should have been posted as an answer -- which is what I'm doing now).

> EDIT 3 (and answer): Done. It turned out that win32com.client couldn't be imported more than once within the same process. And even for the first import it was necessary to regenerate the COM cache and make sure it's not read-only. We have worked around it by not using win32com at all, as it appeared it was only needed for MSXML. The XML processing was rewritten by using python's standard library xml.sax.

Answer (score 1):

The place to start digging is your app. The error message is telling you some variable is `None` when you think it should point to an object. So, find that variable (the error message should tell you exactly where it is), then figure out why that varianle contains `None`.

There's a good chance your code is either silently catching an error, or it's making some assumption that is false. Find that error or assumption, and work backwards from there.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers so far, it's clear that something is None. I'm rather wondering why this error does not reliably expose itself on 2.5.1. It's not an ordinary app, it's a part of a C++ test which writes a python script, and then runs it. So, debugging it is a bit tricky.

Comment: I recommend building CPython 2.5.{0,1,2,3,4} under different directory hierarchies, and seeing exactly which version transitions from working to not working.